# Show that f is a density and find the corresponding cdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$f(x) = \frac{(1+\alpha x)}{2} $ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, where $-1\leq \alpha \leq 1$. Show that $f$ is a density and find the cdf.

I am mainly having trouble with finding the cdf. By definition the cdf of a density function is defined as $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(u) du $$ but i am having difficulty solving this particular one, specifically splitting up the limits of integration correctly. I tried this:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(u) du + \int_{-1}^{x} f(u) du $$

To which i got:

$$\frac{x-1}{2} + \frac{\alpha(x^2 + 1)}{4} $$

I mean it differentiates out correctly to get the density function, but it doesn't mean that my integration was correct.

Comment: For the cdf you should say it is $0$ if $x\le -1$, it is $1$ if $x\ge 1$, and for the rest of the $x$  integrate from $-1$ to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you must split up the integral, why not say
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x f(u) du = \int_{-1}^x f(u) du = \left.\frac{u + \alpha u^2/2}{2}\right|_{-1}^x ...
$$

Comment: I was trying to follow the form i had seen doen with regards to the exponential density. I have a question, what happened to the other bound on x? Isn't it $-1 \leq x \leq 1$? So don't you need to consider that?

Comment: @dc3rd of course, if $x > 1$, we define $F(x)=1$...